# How to find subpage elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a web app and want to find a button with a certain ID that is in a subpage which can be accessed using the nav bar. I have no issues when trying to find a button on the main page by its ID but when I try to do the same it fails to find it and is set as null.

I'm using VS 2019 and running a MVC ASP.NET solution.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const mainPageBtnEle = document.getElementById("main-btn"); // works
    const subPageBtnEle = document.getElementById("sub-btn"); // fails
```

The button's html is the following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="sub-btn">
   Button!
</button>
```

The navbar's html is the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Index">Admin</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
</nav>
```

Please note that the button I'm looking for is part of the "Admin" page and is part of the Index.cshtml view from it.

As the subPageBtnEle gets a null value I cannot trigger any function when clicking it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: how this `"sub-btn"` is render on the page ?

Comment: What is meant by 'sub page'?  Is it another page that's rendered in an iframe?  Or is it a partial view rendered inline?

Comment: "subpage which can be accessed using the nav bar" ...what is a "subpage"? You mean a different HTML page which is mentioned in a hyperlink? If so, then clearly that page is not actually loaded yet, there's only a link to it. Or does the navbar take you to anchors within the current document? Please show us the HTML of your navbar then we can be clear what is going on. Also, show us the HTML of the button you are targeting, so we can be sure you used the right method to select it.

Comment: Edited the question answering these comments

Comment: if you solved it, please add the solution into the "Answers" section below, that's where solutions go - the solution is not part of the question. Then people can vote on it and other future readers with a similar issue can clearly see what the fix was.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, will do it !

Answer (score 2):

Solution: solved this by moving `const subPageBtnEle = document.getElementById("sub-btn");` outside of the `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function ()`.

Because of doing this, now the functionality works as expected.

Thanks everyone for helping !

Comment: thanks for adding as the solution. This seems an odd solution though....normally you put code into that DomContentLoaded so that it doens't run before the elements are created. moving it outside that block increases that risk. I would have expected the solution would be to move that line of code into the Index.cshtml page of the Admin view, where the button actually exists